# Does Windows Phone 7 already support Visual Basic?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7

I just know that it supports C#, but I read things showing in Visual Basic. Does WP7 already support or is it just users creating things?
Thank you.

Comment: Just a note that if you want to use F# on the phone, go here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/08/20/f-windows-phone-7-silverlight-templates-now-on-visual-studio-gallery.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a808a69d-6119-47b7-b858-262be5c49915) available of the Visual Basic tools, but only the C# tools are RTM at the moment.

I doubt that it's a *phone* issue so much as tooling.

Comment: could you explain me the difference of CTP and RTM please?
thanks a lot!

Comment: CTP == Community Technology Preview - meaning it's an "example of how it may work when released".
RTM == Release to Manufacturing which means it's done and ready to ship.

Comment: I believe MS told me a little while ago, that the problem was around including the Visual Basic dll in the mobile framework (my memory is a little hazy, but something around that).  The ironic thing I heard was that someone on the old mobile team (who was canned in the mass cleaning of the team) actually figured out how to make vb.net work on the mobile platform like days before he was let go.  Of course, no body knew this at the time, and so they lost a lot of the information about how he did it.

Comment: mmm.. thank you.
but by "Community" in CTP, does it mean that some people that don't work at Microsoft did it?

Comment: @Alan: No, it means that it's *for* the community, not *by* the community.